# Protobuf-net C#: Adding Fields to the RuntimeTypeModel

Tags: c#, runtime, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, custom-attributes

I am trying to initialize the RuntimeTypeModel dynamically at runtime. I am using the below function which was working until I added the part that includes Fields. Base types in this model would just use the ProtoMember attribute and nothing else (excpet inheriting form the appropriate bas class) to specify what could be serialized. Here is the code that errors.

```
MetaType childMetaData = model[parentType].AddSubType(includeTagNumber++, child);
foreach (MemberInfo fi in child.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Reverse())
{
      if (fi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || fi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
      {
            if (fi.DeclaringType.Equals(child))
            {
                  ProtoMemberAttribute attr = fi.GetCustomAttribute<ProtoMemberAttribute>();
                  if (attr.IsNotNull())
                  {
                        childMetaData.Add(attr.Tag, fi.Name); //Error here...
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

I get an ArgumentException that says it cannot determine the memberName parameter for any of my fields.

**EDIT:**
I looked at the trunk and v1 code for protobuf-net and the following lines are run:

```
MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMember(memberName, Helpers.IsEnum(type) ? BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public : BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if(members != null && members.Length == 1) mi = members[0];
if (mi == null) throw new ArgumentException("Unable to determine member: " + memberName, "memberName");
```

When I run the same lines on the line before the call, they come out as expected with MemberInfo[1] returned... so why? Any help?

Example Class:

```
class SerializedButton : VProtoCapable
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired=true)]
    private int someData

    public int SomeData
    {
        get { return someData; }
        set { someData = value; }
    }

    public SerializedButton() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddField() returns the MetaData for the parent type and not the derived type.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario with same error.  "Unable to determine member: myField"

The problem is that a parent class and child class have myField, the later was redefined (with new) in child class which inherit from base class, so when using RuntimeTypeModel to Add this field for serialization on inherited class it throws that exception.  The call to type.GetMember("myField",...) returns 2 items, one for the child class and one for the parent class, and throws.

Until now there is no official fix for this issue. But this link provides a non official fix to it (changing source code): [Protobuf-net: Using Hidden Members does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735209/protobuf-net-using-hidden-members-does-not-work)